# Set Docker Container's Machine Name in Windows?

Tags: windows, docker

I'm playing with Docker in Windows to make Windows images and containers.  If I powershell into a container and ask for the HostName, I get the short container name, a Hex string.

Is it possible to force the name to be a certain value? Or to have a prefix at least?

Answer (score 0):

According to docker documentation you can set hostname my using --hostname option

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/